# Items in ActionBarCompat are showed always in Overflow

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm using ActionBarCompat in my app, an I want to show one or two items in the action bar

I follwed the guide of google developers, but when I test it, the items are showed in the "Overflow" option (in Nexus 4) and if I tap on the menu button if there exist (ex. Galaxy S3)

What I've doing wrong?

***SOLUTION FOUND***

You can find it in a answer.

Comment: Better to post the solution as an actual Answer.

Comment: @MarkCarter After "few" time .. I see your request, and I have edit my post to separe the question for the answer. Thanks (bit late) for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution so I posted as Answer:

**SOLUTION FOUND**

In the xml of the menu, you have to put the new namespace, to make actionbarcompat work. So there are some options that need this spacename instead of "android". So the solutions is This:

**Old Login menu:**

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_register"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/login_menu_register"/>
```

**New Login Menu (solution) (Look at how is caled "showAsAction")**

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_register"
        shudy:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/login_menu_register"/>
```

**Login.xml (MENU)**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_register"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/login_menu_register"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_register2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="miau"/>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SLog.d(CLASS_NAME + " onCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        findViews();
        buttons();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.shudy.myworld.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and found two solutions:

In the menu xml (Login.xml), use your app name for the showAsAction tag:

instead of:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_register"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/some_icon"
    android:title="@string/login_menu_register" />
```

use:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_register"
    yourappname:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/some_icon"
    android:title="@string/login_menu_register" />
```

I suppose your application's name is shady.

the second solution for me, on the activity class, at the onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem registerMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_register);
    registerMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS); // change this in backcompat
    return true;
}
```

if you are using backCompatibility, change last line:

```
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(registerMenuItem,MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Programatically calling `setShowAsAction` was the magic sauce I needed. I wonder why the XML didn't work.

Comment: in some of my xml when using app compat, the prefix android is needed and sometimes not, depending on the running android version. As far as I remember, android:background is not working in android < 12 and you need to use background only. 
It looks to me that the same thing is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide the icon for these actions so they can appear in the action bar.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:shudy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_register"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/some_icon"
    android:title="@string/login_menu_register" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_register2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/some_icon2"
    android:title="miau" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Doens't Work :S but I found the solution ;)

I will edit my answer to do available for everybody

Answer (score 0):

The question has been updated to include the answer, but for anyone who is interested in the official documentation, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems and pay particular attention to the note about using a custom namespace for the `showAsAction` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ok"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="OK"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have two ways to solute this problem.

1. You need add libs "ActionBarSherlock".This is usage of [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html).

OR
 2. You need add libs "android-Support-v7". If you choice this method ,then your menu.xml need like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:v7="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item
    android:id="..."
    android:icon="..."
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="..."
    v7:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also true for the Android Toolbar in new Material Design concepts in the AppCompat-v21 and API levels 21 and above.