# Hide overflow menu button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to hide title bar and now want to use menu for my app, as you see in the picture below, I set menu button in bottom of page but still overflow menu shows at top and both work, how can I hide the top one and use the button at bottom for menu?

[image]

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452578/items-in-actionbarcompat-are-showed-always-in-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Overflow button at the bottom of the screen is bad! It is deprecated. If you have this button - it means you are targeting really old SDK version. Please read this:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

If you really want to hide the top one - you need either to remove all the elements from options menu (which is not what you want I suppose), or remove action bar. How to remove action bar - is different story and can be googled in 2 clicks

Comment: if I remove the action bar I can not use tabs and if I use default overflow menu, as you see in the picture the apps looks strange on some devices, what is your suggestion ?